# i want to have a htaccess like login.mydomain.com

Tags: .htaccess

am not sure how to make a htaccess to have a thing like this like i have a login page on my website, and my main page starts with www.mydomain.com, and my login page starts with www.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php, so i was wondering if i could make this short and have instead of the long dir i simply have login.mydomain.com which refers to www.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php

this is what i have try for long

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

any help will be appreciated, maybe am totally not making it right

thanks

Comment: If `login.mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` are on same host and point to same `DocumentRoot` then only it is possible.

Comment: yes but i made the www. on htaccess, i got a domain and is only mydomain.com, so i use the htaccess to have the www.mydomain.com automatically install when users type in mydomain.com and it goes www.mydomain.com, so i was wondering maybe i can do the same with htaccess

Comment: yes right now they are pointing to the same DocumentRoot and is working i use the subdomain, and my DNS has automatically creates is own records so what next

Comment: u there anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code **as first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^login\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^myusersaccount/loginaccount/login\.php$ http://login.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: this is working but the www.mydomain.com, is not appearing how can i make it

Comment: If you want URL to be `www.mydomain.com` then check the edit.

Comment: but can i still have the login.mydomain.com to be there when i click on the login page, and the www.mydomain.com will be when i click on the home main page?

Comment: What is current URL (full) of login page?

Comment: my main page has www.mydomain.com before it was mydomain.com, so i use htaccess to automatically insert the www. before the domain, and my login page is www.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php, and now with your help i got login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php but when i type in mydomian.com instead of to insert the www. before the domain it leaves it without the www. and when i click on the login side its does to login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php, this show i need to work more any idea

Comment: i want it to be when i still type mydomain.com it inserts the www.mydomain.com and when i click on the login side it inserts the login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php,

Comment: this helps to get the www.mydomain.com but the login.mydomain.com doesn't open anymore

Comment: now is working but the $ sign is preventing it from opening because the dollar sign is at last login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php$ so is preventing it, can i remove the dollar sign will it course more problems

Comment: ah that was a typo, fixed it now.

Comment: lol is there any way i can also hide the directories and make it only login.mydomain.com is that possible?

Comment: just like this login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php, will open this login.mydomain.com, without the dir been at the back?

Comment: just this login.mydomain.com

Comment: OK, give me an example of directory URL that you want to hide OR better yet create a new question linking this one to keep the slate clean.

Comment: ok checkout my new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951304/i-want-to-make-a-htaccess-to-have-a-short-link

Comment: i you understand what i mean by my question there because instead of making it too long i rather cut the question short so just want to remove the Url directory on login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php and make it like this login.mydomain.com, so that when i access login.mydomain.com it won't take my to login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php,

Comment: instead it stays on the login.mydomain.com, with the same page, just like to hide the of myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php on login.mydomain.com, and this login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php will now be this login.mydomain.com and does the same work