# i want to make a htaccess to have a short link

Tags: .htaccess

just wish to present this long link login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php, to this login.mydomain.com, so that when i access login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php, it take me to this login.mydomain.com, here is the code i use in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^login\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^myusersaccount/loginaccount/login\.php$ http://login.mydomain.com {REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `R` flag from this rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php [L]
```

Comment: and i hope you understand my question

Comment: Ok made an edit, try it now. Now if you goto `http://login.mydomain.com` it will load `http://login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php` without changing the URL.

Comment: yes that is what am saying maybe you didn't understand my question i mean when you go to [http://login.mydomain.com] it will load as the same without loading to [http://login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php], just want to hide the directories this directories [/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php]

Comment: That is what current updated code does, make sure to test in a new browser. URL will show `http://login.mydomain.com` but content will come from: `http://login.mydomain.com/myusersaccount/loginaccount/login.php`

Comment: you the best i really appreciate it

Comment: yeah it does, but now another problem when i login now it deleted the [myusersaccount] and go to /loginaccount/index.php, and which is not normal because have no such fill on my page, so do do i get it work perfect because it need to still have the [myusersaccount] so that it can connect to /loginaccount/index.php, and having this [myusersaccount] at first because this is where all the fills and dir are this [myusersaccount]

Comment: oh takes man i figure it out already no worries i got it now i need to make some changes in the login.php, so i did and it working perfect now

Comment: oh perfect, you figured it all out :)